# A "seemingly" classic problem about integral. Need help......

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability measure space, and let $f\in\mathcal{L}_{+}^1(\mu)$ such that $\ln f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, prove that
$$\lim_{p\to0+}\int_X \frac{f^p-1}{p}d\mu=\int_X\ln fd\mu.$$
and that
$$\lim_{p\to0+}\left(\int_X f^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\exp{\int_X\ln fd\mu}.$$
It seems to be difficult to apply the Lebesgue convergence theorem, but if $f(X)\subset[\delta,M]$ for some $\delta>0$ and $M<\infty$, the LDC can be successfully applied.

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that for any $t>1$, $p\in]0,1[$,
   $$\frac{t^p-1}{p}\leq t-1.$$
   And for $t<1$,
   $$0>\frac{t^p-1}{p}\searrow\ln t.$$
   Thus $|\frac{t^p-1}{p}|\leq|t-1|+|\ln t|$. By assumption $|t-1|+|\ln t|$ is integrable. Then by LDC and Heine theorem
   $$\lim_{p\to0+}\int_X\frac{f^p-1}{p}d\mu=\int_X\ln fd\mu.$$
2. 

\begin{align*}
    \lim_{p\to0+}\left(\int_X f^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}&=\lim_{p\to0+}\exp{\frac{1}{p}\ln\int_X f^pd\mu}\\
    &=\exp\lim_{p\to0+}\frac{1}{p}\ln\left(p\int_X \ln fd\mu+1\right)
\end{align*}
As for any real number $c$, $\lim_{p\to0+}\frac{\ln(pc+1)}{p}=c$, so
$$\lim_{p\to0+}\left(\int_X f^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\exp{\int_X \ln fd\mu}.$$